# Sumifs using 3 conditions (dates/specific text)

Tags: excel, conditional-statements, formulas, sumifs

Please excuse the basic (I imagine) question.

I have attempted to use Sumifs to Total up my expenses based on two categories.
These two categories are dates and type of expense.

If an expense occurs in a certain week it will be totalled under whichever category it comes under.

The formula worked for the dates 1/04/2018 to 8/04/18, however, as soon as I tried to update the dates to the week after the formula did not work as I intended.

Please find sample code below along with some screenshot of my file.

```
=SUMIFS(  
    'Expenses - 2nd Quarter'!$D$3:$D$300,  
    'Expenses - 2nd Quarter'!$B$3:$B$300, ">="&'Weekly Budget'!$D$1,  
    'Expenses - 2nd Quarter'!$B$3:$B$300, "<"&$E$1,  
    'Expenses - 2nd Quarter'!$A$3:$A$300, 'Weekly Budget'!$A7)  
-  
 SUMIFS(    
    'Expenses - 2nd Quarter'!$C$3:$C$300,    
    'Expenses - 2nd Quarter'!$B$3:$B$300, ">="&'Weekly Budget'!$D$1,  
    'Expenses - 2nd Quarter'!$B$3:$B$300, "<"&$E$1,  
    'Expenses - 2nd Quarter'!$A$3:$A$300, 'Weekly Budget'!$A7)
```

---

Weekly Expenses Tab
[image: img]

---

Expenses - 2nd Quarter Tab
[image: img]

Comment: I fail to understand the point of the subtraction operation. btw, *'did not work as I intended'* is not a valid error description.

Comment: The subtraction operation has the same effect as the first operation. It is merely there for the remittance column in the second screenshot. I could probably subtract remittance an easier way. But i haven't put much thought into that yet.

Fair point, my error is that the formula spits out 0 when I change the date (D1) to anything other than 1/04/18.

It works fine when using 1/04/18 and 8/04/18, as shown by C6 in the first screenshot. However, when I change the date it will not pick up my entries in the second entry from A10:D12

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find anything wrong with your formula. The only reason for not working is to enter wrong dates or dates in wrong order. Otherwise, you should get what you want.
And of course `pivot table` is always a good tool to do what you indent to do.

Comment: Sorry, how do you mean wrong dates?

Please refer to my comment above in reply to Jeeped for a more accurate description of my error. 

A pivot table would work, I just would like to quickly be able to update the range the data is looking (i.e., 1/04/18 - 8/04/18 entries for one week) then (8/04/18 - 15/04/18) the next.

I can do this with pivot tables and sumifs fairly quickly, but I would like to do instantaneously.

Comment: Why did you include **'Weekly Budget'!** in part of the formula and omitted in another part? If your formula is indeed in **Weekly Budget** sheet, then you don't need reference to the sheet and if your formula is in another sheet, then this is the reason for your formula not to work!

Comment: That was poor coding on my part, the cell I am referencing is indeed on the Weekly Budget sheet along with my formula, thus it is not needed.

Sadly, removing the sheet reference does not fix the error.